# How do you say "tramitador" in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, nouns, terminology, american-english

In Latin America, where for years illiteracy was the norm, and many people *still* do not speak Spanish as a first language, it is common for an agent to perform procedures with government offices on behalf of their “clients”.  They will fill out applications, stand in line, navigate their way through the red tape and in general expedite government  processes.

In Spanish, this person is called a ***[tramitador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aGMy27Z)***.

He may be a lawyer, but it is not a requirement. The primary requirement is patience, and knowledge of the “in´s and out´s” of the bureaucratic nonsense that permeates much of the official processes and keeps the government in business.

I am looking for a word in English which will work for general usage. Usually when we do the translations we just use the Spanish word with a brief explanation.

I have found [“acceptance agent”](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/acceptance-agent-program), but  only in connection with people working in Internal Revenue Service business on behalf of foreigners filing for the ITIN (Individual Taxpayer Identification Number).

And the word “[expeditor](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/expeditor.html)” seems to be restricted to the business of transportation of goods and packages.

Is there a word in English that will work in this usage?

Comment: **Agent**, **advocate**, or **representative** are commonly used to refer to someone in that capacity.  **Surrogate** might also apply, but that would be someone who does it in their place rather than assisting.

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish, we also call that person "gestor". Whenever you have this kind of doubts, apart from resorting to this site, you can google the word in question and type "proz" or "kudoz", a famous site for translators.

Even the word "trámites" is a bit troublesome to translate. According to the context, we can use "paperwork", "steps", "formalities", "procedures", etc.

My choice for "tramitador" would be "paperwork facilitator". Some colleagues suggested the same, as well as other options, [here](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/spanish_to_english/law_patents/348088-gestor.html).

Comment: If the primary role of the tramitador is to run around and stand in line, he could be a *runner*. // Paperwork is what I say for trámites.  // Consider Spanish SE. // *Expediter* works for me.

Comment: Would "liaison" be an appropriate translation?